# how to find the coordinate of a point where sum of distances between this point and five other points be minimal

Tags: geometry, coordinates, distance, minimum, centroid

I have coordinates of five points let say A, B, C, D, E  and I need to find the coordinate of a point (M) where the distance of each point to the M be minimal.
so sum of AM, BM, CM, DM, EM is minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is linear transformation but you can try the harvesine formula.

Answer (score 1):

You have already used tag [centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_finite_set_of_points), but it is known that centroid as arithmetic mean of a finite set of points `minimizes the sum of squared Euclidean distances between itself and each point in the set`.

So it's enough to find centroid coordinates as

```
M.X = (A.X + B.X + C.X + D.X + E.X) / 5 
M.Y = (A.Y + B.Y + C.Y + D.Y + E.Y) / 5
```